# Unit Testing functional components with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I have written test case for the post.js to find 3 p tag but it's throwing an error. How do I properly test this component?

Post.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Post.css';

const Post = (props) => {

    const displayPosts = (props) => {

    const { posts } = props;

    if ( posts.length > 0 ){

        return(

            posts.map( (post) => {

                return(

                    <div className = "Post">

                        <p className = "name"> <b>Name :</b> {post.name}</p>

                        <p className = "email"> <b> Email :</b> {post.email}</p>

                        <p className = "body"> <b> Body :</b> {post.body}</p>

                    </div>
                )
            })
        )
    }

    }
    return (
        <div className = "Posts">
            { displayPosts(props) } 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Post;
```

Post.test.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { shallow, configure } from "enzyme";
import Post from "./Post";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("Post", () => {
    it("includes three paragraphs", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Post />);
        expect(wrapper.find("p")).toHaveLength(3);
      });
});
```

Comment: your test is not passing in any values for `posts` so your render function is returning nothing in side your `<div className = "Posts">`

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to testing myself. However, at a quick glance your testing from a shallow perspective while your 'p' tags are actually rendered/nested deeper (in your 'displayPosts' component) than where you are testing. I would bet that if you console.log the wrapper object in your test code you would see a single div logged.

From the enzyme docs: "Shallow rendering is useful to constrain yourself to testing a component as a unit, and to ensure that your tests aren't indirectly asserting on behavior of child components."